# What brain regions consume the most energy?

Tags: neuroscience

It's well known that the human brain consumes roughly 20% of the body's energy, and that [grey matter is much more energy-intensive than white matter](https://www.brainfacts.org/brain-anatomy-and-function/anatomy/2019/how-much-energy-does-the-brain-use-020119).

Beyond this basic information, it seems difficult to search for the total energy consumption of the brain broken down by lobe, or ideally further. For instance, how much power is consumed by the typical hippocampus, averaged over a typical human lifespan?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! This is well outside my area, but I think you need to clarify and focus your question. For example, it is well known that energy consumption in different regions varies depending on what the brain is doing.

Comment: @tyersome I'm not sure what you mean, but I want the time-average values for a typical human.